# How to unify all the "-" signs?

Tags: python

I have a simple program that takes data from the user. Here is an abbreviated version of it:

```
a = "0-1"
b = "0‑1"

print(a in b)  # prints False
```

Problem:

> ord('-') for a = 45

> ord('‑') for b = 8209

How can I make sure that the "-" sign is always the same and checking a in b returns True?

Comment: Post the relevant code as text in the question; don't link to an outside resource as the *only* way to understand the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "always the same"? Does your text contain a mix of hyphens, en-dashes, em-dashes, etc, and you want to standardize on a single character?

Comment: @chepner please open a link with code and run it. There are two "-", but in unicode there aren't the same.

Comment: No, per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), *you* need to edit your question to avoid depending on the link.

Comment: @chepner the second dash is `'\u2011'`.

Comment: If you only need to replace _this_ weird minus sign, then just do just that. If there are other cases, your question is incomplete and should be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most robust way would be to use the [`unidecode` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to convert all non-ASCII characters to their closest [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) equivalent automatically.

```
import unidecode
print(unidecode.unidecode(a) in unidecode.unidecode(b))
```

Comment: I like this. One this to note though is that this is not standard lib, so you need to be able to add it as a dependency.

Comment: @PirateNinjas no it's not, probably because the Unicode tables don't change on the same schedule as Python releases.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear if your example is part of a more general, but for the example provided you can handle this using `replace`:

```
a = "0-1"
b = "0‑1"

print(a.replace("‑", "-") in b.replace("‑", "-"))  # True
```

I've called replace on both sides, because it's not clear which side is your input and which is not. In principle though this comes down to "sanitize your input".

If this is more of a general problem, you might want to look at using `.translate` to produce a mapping of characters to apply in one go.